# Is saying that $Re(f(z))\to 0, z\to \infty$ "correspondent" to saying $Re(f(z))\le M, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}, M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ M$ constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ entire . Is saying that $Re(f(z))\to 0, z\to \infty$ "correspondent" to saying $Re(f(z))\le M, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}, M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ M$ constant?

Comment: What do you mean by "correspondent"? That the real part approaches $0$ as $z\to \infty$ implies that the real part is bounded, but it is stronger than that.

Comment: I meant the relation between the two statements, but couldnt find the proper term. Sorry for my english and thanks for your response

Comment: @helplessKirk perhaps you mean "equivalent"?

Comment: not exactly equivalent , more like the first implies the second

Answer (score 0):

If $$\lim_{|z|\to\infty } \mbox{Re} (f(z)) =0$$
then $$\mbox{Re} (f(z))$$ is bounded. But this gives a contradiction with  Little Picard Theorem.